# How to submit a form on change?

Tags: javascript, ios, wifi

The question is specifically about the **Captive Network Assistant**.

I have tried using vanilla JavaScript,

```
<form action="">
    <select name="test" onchange="this.form.submit()">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

As well using jQuery, in case there was a browser incompatibility issue.

```
$('select').on('change', function () {
    $(this).closest('form').submit();
});
```

However, none of them work and Captive Portal issues are not an easy cookie to debug. Is there a known solution?

Answer (score 1):

As i remember `submit()` method doesn't work properly in jQuery.

Try using JavaScript: `document.getElementById('ID').submit();`

I had similar problem but this solved everything, so hole it helps You.

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks fine. You probably want to fill in the `action` attribute of your form and possibly use the `method` and `enctype` attributes as well.

Here is a working copy of your code on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x5J4A/)

Comment: Action default value is `GET`. `enctype` defaults to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. You have missed the part where I said that this is specific to `Apple Captive Portal Assistant`.