# Getting values from a select input from database

Tags: php, mysql, input, while-loop

I have the following code that if a user is selected, I want their values to appear in an input box that eventually I will change the values for.

```
if ($stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM team_rankings")) {

    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($ranking_id, $ranking_user_id, $ranking_firstname, $ranking_username, $ranking_division, $ranking_wins, $ranking_losses); 

    //var_dump($stmt);

    if (!$stmt) {
        throw new Exception($con->error);
    }

$stmt->store_result();
    echo "<select name = 'member'>";
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {

     echo "<option value = '{$ranking_user_id}'";
        echo ">{$ranking_firstname}</option>";
    }
    echo "</select>";


    }   else {
        echo "<p>There are not any team players yet.</p>";
        }
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
?><br><br>
    <label>Win
        <input type="text" value="<?php echo $ranking_wins; ?>">
    </label>
    <label>Loss
        <input type="text" value="<?php echo $ranking_losses; ?>">
    </label>
```

How can I structure this so that only the user's win and losses will show up from what was selected in the select input.

Comment: Fill the option values with their **userid** and extend your query **... WHERE userid=userid**

Comment: School project going on here ?? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31680311/ordering-by-a-selected-column-from-database/31680422?noredirect=1#comment51302917_31680422

Comment: @bub I updated my question with your recommendations. The values still do not reflect what is in my db.

Comment: I think what you asked is to have wins and losses for selected user. What you want here is to pull all the users into member selection. Then, when add onChange JS event to the drop down which submits the page. Then on the same page check if values are set ... well :)... there's a lot to be added here, but you first need to say that's what you really want :)

Comment: @hummingBird Yes, that is what I want. If Joe is selected from the drop-down box and he has 3 wins and 2 losses, I want those values to show. If Ann was selected and she has 2 wins and 3 losses, I want those values to show, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a how-to, but you'll need to fill in some details.

First of all, you need to either add `onChange` even to your drop down and then implement the functionality to auto-submit the form OR (simpler) ad a submit button. That way, your page will require user to click "Submit" after changing the value in drop down, but that should be OK.

When this is done, you need to add something like this in the beginning of your script:

```
$selectedUser = intval($_POST['selected_user_id']); // or $_GET
$wins = 0;
$losses = 0;
```

(I did some basic input validation here by converting to int - not sure if this would work). 
Then, add something like this to your `while` loop:

```
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {

     echo "<option value = '{$ranking_user_id}'"; 
     if ($ranking_user_id == $selectedUser) {
        echo 'selected';
        $wins = $ranking_wins;
        $losses = $ranking_losses;
     }
     echo ">{$ranking_firstname}</option>";
}
```

That will allow your selected user to stay selected after you click submit.

Lastly, you need to put wins and losses:

```
    <label>Win
        <input type="text" value="<?php echo $wins; ?>">
    </label>
    <label>Loss
        <input type="text" value="<?php echo $losses; ?>">
    </label>
```

Note that I used my own wins and losses, and not those values that were bind in each while-pass.

Note 2: your form should have something like this:

```
<form action=<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?> method="post">
```

This way when you submit you'll just send the data to the same script.

Comment: Why would I set `$wins` and `$losses` to 0 when they have actual values coming from my database? My goal was for these values to be displayed and then have the option to submit the changes when the values have been modified. Like 4 wins changed to 5, and then submit. Would this work for that?

Comment: you set them to 0 because you're going to set them to real values later on (in the while loop).

Comment: ok, how would I go about the onchange event? I don't know too much about JS.

Comment: you don't need onchange thing. it's a 'neat' way to do it, but it wouldn't work in an environment where js is disabled. but if you really want it, here's a link that can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16767871/how-to-submit-a-form-on-change

Comment: i didn't note here that your form need to have a proper action set ... i'm going to update the answer

Comment: Well if this is in a form, then how will the values of $wins and $losses be added in, if I don't want to hit a submit button until the values have been changed?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84498/discussion-between-hummingbird-and-becky).